# Is there a way to debug why a chrome request was queued?

Tags: google-chrome, networking, chromium, request-queueing

Background: Chrome has a requests queue. It will queue delayable requests under some circumstances. But I found it hard to determine which requests are causing the requests queuing.

My question is: do we have a way to dive into the root cause of the queuing issue ?

[source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/74.0.3693.6/services/network/resource_scheduler.cc#388)

[chrome doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#timing)

Comment: Looks like that code is part of network stack which is handled by the browser process. Why not set a breakpoint and start debugging the browser process to find out?

Comment: Ok so assuming the [user docs are accurate](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#:~:text=the%20Timing%20tab%3A-,Queueing,-.%20The%20browser%20queues), it looks like you really have two primary cases to explore 1) higher priority requests and 2) number of requests from the same origin (only applies to http 1/1.1 and capped at 6). The third case mentioned involves allocating disk so i would look at that last. I would guess your issue is #2 as it is pretty easy to launch  more than 6 requests.

Comment: Max parallel requests is the most probable cause. See here for good answers from spanning several years in time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser. [This page](https://blog.bluetriangle.com/blocking-web-performance-villain) also

Comment: The question is from@z-better but bounty is from @brad? didn't know that was possible. Anway, my answer is there :-)

Comment: @LMC Yes, what good are fake internet points if you can't spend them on something?  :-)  I often add bounties to others' questions, especially if it's remotely related to what I'm working on anyway.

Comment: @brad Kind attitude :-):-):-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## HTTP/1.1 vs HTTP/2

For HTTP/2 queuing has a different meaning and analysis. Read this great article on [Head of Line Blocking (HOLB)](https://engineering.salesforce.com/the-full-picture-on-http-2-and-hol-blocking-7f964b34d205/).

[Here's my analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52770802/2834978) of TTFB timings using Wireshark which could be a complement for the debug job.

### HTTP/2

HOLB may have 2 causes: HTTP and TCP. Request blocking can still happen (perhaps over TCP reasons).

Having a HAR file for the page/site, find entries with `.blocked > 50` over `timings` (please, read HTTP/1.1 analysis below)

```
    "timings": {
      "blocked": 286,
      "dns": 0,
      "connect": 0,
      "ssl": 0,
      "send": 0,
      "wait": 605,
      "receive": 163
    }
```

`jq -r '.log.entries | to_entries[] | select(.value.response.httpVersion == "HTTP/2" and .value.timings.blocked > 0) | [.key, .value.request.url, .value.timings.blocked]' stackoverflow.com.har`

Result

```
[12,"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/05b09a797fd0c59d1627b30fb4cdba01?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",140]
[19,"https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHqqo.jpg?s=32&g=1",319]
[22,"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AItbvmmvptZFLppl8vyYo83v1QOQJwt-90sdRzBnyw9Z=k-s32",7]
[23,"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJwXX0y4AkD3eL_6KvrwRXLmBviBVEXEb7X6U1WA=k-s32",6]
[27,"https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdIyT.jpg?s=32&g=1",314]
[48,"https://i.stack.imgur.com/65UsL.jpg?s=32&g=1",297]
[61,"https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLQJy.jpg?s=32&g=1",286]
```

### HTTP/1.1

There are several reasons why Chrome could be [queuing a request](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#timing-explanation) (as any other browser)

> Queueing. The browser queues requests when:
>
> - There are higher priority requests.
> - There are already six TCP connections open for this origin, which is the limit. Applies to HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 only.
> - The browser is briefly allocating space in the disk cache

From the developer's tools Network tab, save the requests with `Save all as HAR with content` and analyze the `timings` object of each request

```
    "timings": {
      "blocked": 2.0329999979403803,
      "dns": -1,
      "ssl": -1,
      "connect": -1,
      "send": 0.397,
      "wait": 189.6199999998943,
      "receive": 296.10200000024633,
      "_blocked_queueing": 1.1759999979403801
    }
```

HAR could be filtered with `jq`, e.g. **find entries with `_blocked_queueing > 50`**

`jq -r '.log.entries | to_entries[] | if(.value.timings._blocked_queueing > 50) then [.key, .value.request.url, .value.timings._blocked_queueing,.value.timings.blocked ] else empty end' stackoverflow.com.har`

Result:

```
[
  21,
  "https://graph.facebook.com/4191055284264423/picture?type=large",
  160.28299999743467,
  160.66799999743466
]
[
  66,
  "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotoslab/v13/BngbUXZYTXPIvIBgJJSb6s3BzlRRfKOFbvjojISmb2Rm.ttf",
  55.99899999651825,
  109.53999999651825
]
[
  67,
  "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotoslab/v13/BngbUXZYTXPIvIBgJJSb6s3BzlRRfKOFbvjoa4Omb2Rm.ttf",
  56.85599999560509,
  56.85599999560509
]
```

Then we could **inspect 6 preceding entries** of one of those requests

`jq -r --argjson idx 67 '.log.entries[($idx - 6):($idx + 1)] | .[] | [.request.url, .time, .timings]' stackoverflow.com.har`

Or get the **highest `dns`**

`jq -r '.log.entries | sort_by(.timings.dns|floor)[-1] | .timings.dns, .request.url' stackoverflow.com.har`

```
438.551
https://example.com
```

Google offers an [online HAR Analyzer](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/) that could be used similar to Dev tools Network pane.

Hovering over a request on the `Waterfall` column, the details of a request can be seen. As a first approach, long queuing requests could be preceded by one or several requests with high values on any of the items.

[image]

Using the command line below to get a csv and then make a chart with

- date as Unix timestamp [ms]
- request time [ms]
- _blocked_queueing [ms]

```
jq -r '.log.entries | to_entries[] | [.value.startedDateTime, .value.serverIPAddress, .key, ((.value.startedDateTime[0:19] + "Z"|fromdateiso8601)*1000 + (.value.startedDateTime[20:23]|tonumber)), .value.time, .value.timings._blocked_queueing ] | @csv' stackoverflow.com.har | tee stackoverflow.com.har.csv
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Can you please provide steps to generate this graph too ?

Comment: @maheshreddy the output of the last command will return a csv that can be used to generate the chart with LibreOffice for example.